# Manage the transitions between different menus in a Flash based kiosk application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I want to know how to design a Flash CS4(AS3) based kiosk application where the screen changes according to the user events(to change the screens [like this](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/samples/gamestatemanagement)). Preferably use xml to describe the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a controller class that would handle the processing of information as well as the results of the user interaction, this class would dispatch events to a view management class which would handle sending appropriate information to each screens and the tweening and transitions effects between those screens.